# What syntax is required for dynamic $_POST[reference.$i] referencing?

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I have some data in my $_POST array that is named with numerical suffixes. How can I access these in a loop?

Below doesn't seem to work:

```
for($i=1;$i<=count($_POST)/5;$i++) {

    $name = $_POST[tblAppendGrid_name_.$i]
    $display = $_POST[tblAppendGrid_display_.$i]
    $type = $_POST[tblAppendGrid_type_.$i]
    $maxlength = $_POST[tblAppendGrid_maxlength_.$i]
    $width = $_POST[tblAppendGrid_width_.$i]

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're simply concatenating a number to a string, same syntax as always:

```
$name = $_POST['tblAppendGrid_name_'.$i];
```

Still, there's a better way to do this: change the names of your form elements to

```
<input type='text' name='tblAppendGrid[name][]' />
```

And your post array will be a multi-dimensional array anyways:

```
$name = $_POST['tblAppendGrid']['name'][0];//first element
$name = $_POST['tblAppendGrid']['name'][4];//fifth element
```

Also keep in mind that whatever conditional expression you use in a `for` loop, it'll be re-evaluated every time the loop is executed: `count($_POST)/5` will be executed 5 times, best write:

```
for ($i=1, $j=count($_POST)/5;$i<=$j;++$i)
{//compute $j once, use in second expression
    //code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's explained at **Language Reference → Types → [Arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)**:

> The key can either be an integer or a string. [...]
>
> Additionally the following key casts will occur:
>
> - Strings containing valid integers will be cast to the integer type. E.g. the key "8" will actually be stored under 8. [...]

At **Language Reference → Types → [Strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)** you can find the different possibilies to generate strings dynamically. For your use case you probably want [double-quoted](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) strings.

If you have access to the client-side form design, you'll possibly want to [force arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays) anyway.